# Find object that corresponds - getting a comment system to work?

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, while-loop, richtextbox

This is how everything *should* work when the iFrameOn function runs:

1. Turn the designMode of all iFrames on
2. Find the three "buttons" ('a' link elements) - that when clicked affect its corresponding iFrame - depending on its className
3. Put those "buttons" into a multidimensional array/object i.e target.rtfID.x
4. Whenever a "button" is clicked, find its corresponding iFrame through the object and send the iFrame's id as an argument for another function.

Currently, however, whenever any of the buttons are clicked they all affect the same iFrame. I realize this is likely due to my usage of the loops, but I can't figure out how to make it all work. There are no errors in the console.

```
function iFrameOn() {
    var rtfContainer, rtContainer, richTxt, richTxtId,
        rtf = document.querySelectorAll('div > form > iframe'), //Rich Text Field
        newPost = document.getElementById('richTextField').contentDocument.body,
        target = {}, rtfIndex = 0;
    //Turn iFrames On
    while (rtfIndex < rtf.length) {
        rtfID = rtf[rtfIndex].id;
        if (rtf[rtfIndex].contentDocument.designMode != 'On') {
            rtf[rtfIndex].contentDocument.designMode = 'On';
        }
        newPost.innerHTML = "<i style=\"color:#DDDDDD;\">What's up?</i>";   
        newPost.addEventListener('blur', function() {
            if (newPost.innerHTML == '') {
                newPost.innerHTML = "<i style=\"color:#DDDDDD;\">What's up?</i>";
            }
        }, false);
        document.getElementById('richTextField').contentWindow.addEventListener(
            'focus',
            function() {
                if (newPost.innerHTML == "<i style=\"color:#DDDDDD;\">What's up?</i>") {
                    newPost.innerHTML = '';
                }
            },
            false
        );
        rtContainer = rtf[rtfIndex].nextElementSibling; //Next Element Sibling should be a div
        console.log('rtContainer is: '+rtContainer);
        richTxt = rtContainer.childNodes;
        console.log('richTxt is: '+richTxt);
        for (var i = 0; i < richTxt.length; i++) {
            if (richTxt[i].nodeType != 1 ||
                (richTxt[i].nodeType == 1 &&
                    (richTxt[i].className == 'submit_button sbmtPost'
                        || richTxt[i].className == "")
                )
            ) {
                continue;
            }
            richTxtId = richTxt[i].id;
            target.rtfID = {};
            switch (richTxt[i].className) {
                case 'richText bold':
                    if (target.rtfID.bold != richTxtId) {
                        target.rtfID.bold = richTxtId;
                        console.log(target.rtfID.bold+' is associated with: '+rtfID);
                    }
                    break;
                case 'richText underline':
                    if (target.rtfID.underline != richTxtId) {
                        target.rtfID.underline = richTxtId;
                        console.log(target.rtfID.underline+' is associated with: '+rtfID);
                    }
                    break;
                case 'richText italic':
                    if (target.rtfID.italic != richTxtId) {
                        target.rtfID.italic = richTxtId;
                        console.log(target.rtfID.italic+' is associated with: '+rtfID);
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    console.log('Error with commenting system!');
                    break;
            }
        }
        var obj = target.rtfID;
        for (var prop in obj) {
            if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) { 
                console.log("prop: " + prop + " value: " + obj[prop]);
                switch(prop) {
                    case 'bold':
                        document.getElementById(obj[prop]).addEventListener(
                            'click',
                            function() {
                                bold(obj[prop]);
                            },
                            false
                        );
                        break;
                    case 'underline':
                        document.getElementById(obj[prop]).addEventListener(
                            'click',
                            function() {
                                Underline(obj[prop]);
                            },
                            false
                        );
                        break;
                    case 'italic':
                        document.getElementById(obj[prop]).addEventListener(
                            'click',
                            function() {
                                Italic(obj[prop]);
                            },
                            false
                        );
                        break;
                    default: 
                        console.log('Error in for...in loop');
                }
            } else {console.log('error');}
        }
        rtfIndex++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Without having an easy way to test/check, I'd bet your problem is with the fact that you should not define functions within a loop--it leads to problems like this. The inner functions continue to have access to the outer scope, so by the time they execute, they will be grabbing info on the last iframe in your loop. You can get around this by passing the value which varies in the loop into a function which itself returns the function you want.

Comment: That seemed to be the problem. Any way I can avoid defining functions within loops? Only reason I did so is because my rich text functions take parameters and I can't put arguments into the addEventListener method. EDIT: Spoke too soon. I can't go back and forth between the iFrames. Now it only affects the last iFrame it finds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do things like this:

```
function createBolder (val) {
    return function () {
        bold(val);
    };
}

document.getElementById(obj[prop]).addEventListener(
    'click',
    createBolder(obj[prop]),
    false
);
```

or if you really want to keep things inline:

```
document.getElementById(obj[prop]).addEventListener(
    'click',
    (function (val) {
        return function () {
            bold(val);
        };
    }(obj[prop])), // This function call executes immediately (i.e., while still
                   // going through the loop, so the current value of obj[prop]
                   // will be stored inside this function with its own local copy
                   // rather than using the value of obj and prop by the time
                   // the function is executed (probably the completion of the loop))
    false
);
```